# close window icon in vanilla gnome

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-panel, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I switched to vanilla gnome shell using `sudo apt install gnome-session`. Then installed `Pixel saver` gnome shell extension. Now I have orange close button in maximized window mode that's stuck from the previous Ubuntu theme [image: Close button]. Can anyone please tell me how to get the vanilla gnome simple cross mark for this case too? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround here: https://github.com/deadalnix/pixel-saver/issues/132:

```
cd ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/pixelsaver@deadalnix.me/themes
mv Ambiance Ambiance.bak
ln -s default Ambiance
```